# ActiveRecord multiple joins and count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have the following models:

User:

```
has_one :extraction
```

Extraction:

```
belongs_to: user
has_many :pages
```

Pages:

```
belongs_to :extraction
```

Now I want to return all the users and each of the user's page count. I want this in a single query.

#### My Code:

```
@users = User.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN extractions on users.id = extractions.id INNER JOIN pages on extractions.id = pages.extraction_id").
  select("users.*").
  select("COUNT(pages.id) AS total_page_count").
  uniq("users.id").
  group("users.id").
  order(build_order_string).
  paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: custom_cookie_per_page_page_results)
```

Returns that one of the tested users has `276` pages. Whereas if I execute the code manually, i.e. `User.find(1).extraction.pages.count`, this returns `180`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems overly complicated. Wouldn't this do the trick:

```
# user.rb
has_one :extraction
has_many :pages, through: :extractions
```

and then load users with pages:

```
@users = User.includes(:pages).order(...).paginate(...)
```

This will only generate two queries, and you can get each user's page count like this:

```
@users.each{ |user| puts user.pages.size }
```

Comment: Rails way approach. I like it. Also thx for the hint with the has many through.

Answer (score 1):

I had a typo.

It must be:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN extractions on users.id = extractions.user_id INNER JOIN pages on extractions.id = pages.extraction_id").
```